# Expectation of Gaussian r.v. conditioned on positive r.v.s with positive covariances is positive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose that $(X_1,\dotsc,X_K)^T \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$, with $\mathrm{cov}(X_i, X_j) > 0$ for all $i,j$. Prove that
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_K  1\{ X_1> 0, \dotsc, X_{K-1}> 0 \} ] > 0$$
where $1\{ A \}$ is the indicator function of $A$.

Comment: Did you not like "$X_i$" for some reason?

Comment: I observe that if $X_1, ..., X_k$ are random variables then $\{X_1>0, X_2>0, ..., X_{k-1}>0\}$ is an event and so $E[X_K|X_1>0, X_2>0, ..., X_{k-1}>0]$ is not a random variable, it is just an expectation,  so it does not make sense to speak of it "holding almost surely." On the other hand $E[X_k|X_1, ..., X_{k-1}]$ is a random variable so it may make sense to talk about some event related to this holding almost surely.

Comment: Apologies, removed almost surely. The statement is now what I intended.

Comment: Changed notation $X \gets \Delta$ as per suggestion.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{E}[X_K  \mid X_1> 0, \dotsc, X_{K-1}> 0 ]$ mean ? Conditional expectations are usually defined with respect to random variables, not events.

Comment: Hopefully OK now?

Comment: Did you prove it's true if $K=1$?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Expectations conditioned on events are quite common (eg: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101793/expectation-of-x-given-x-y-a/3105728 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258385/conditional-expectation-of-a-geometric-random-variable-conditioned-on-the-event https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248407/how-to-calculate-expectation-conditioning-by-an-event)

Comment: Its true for $K=2$ ($K=1$ is of no interest) trivially by the closed form expression for conditional of MVN. However, moving to three dimensions with that approach requires a matrix inverse, and reasoning about the associated linear algebra is hard. I'm hoping there exists a probabilistic/geometric argument instead.

Comment: I have a proof for this now, will post it up when I have some time for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Minor observation: Proving $E[X_k|(X_1+...+X_{k-1})>0]$ is easier since (assuming the variables are jointly Gaussian) we can just write $Y=X_1+...+X_{k-1}$ and it reduces to proving the statement on a system of 2 jointly Gaussian variables $(Y, X_k)$. In the spirit of this observation, I wonder if the original statement can be proven by considering $E[X_k|X_1,...,X_{k-1}]$ for (almost) all cases when $X_i\geq 0$ for $i \in \{1, ..., k-1\}$ and then integrating these out. I also wonder if this is the approach that Oxonon alludes to.

Comment: @Michael It looks easier, but... it's true?

Comment: @leonbloy I assume the fact indeed holds for the case of 2 jointly Gaussians, which the modified statement $E[X_k|(X_1+...+X_{k-1})>0]>0$ reduces to. I don't know if the original statement can be proven in the way I suggest.  There is an answer that suggests the original statement is true, and Oxonon also suggests the original statement is true.  I don't know how to verify.

Comment: @Michael The original property is true (we trust), but your modified condition is much weaker (and hence your modified property is much stronger), no?

Comment: @leonbloy : The modified property is "weaker" in the sense that $$\{X_1>0, ..., X_{k-1}>0\} \subseteq \{X_1+...+X_{k-1}>0\}$$ but it is not clear if this means anything in terms of conditional expectations when conditioning on "weak" or "strong." Generally, if $A\subseteq B$ we cannot infer anything about $E[X|A]$ versus $E[X|B]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows immediately from the more general result in

Pitt, Loren D. "Positively correlated normal variables are associated." The Annals of Probability (1982): 496-499.